# Pass $http from Controller to Directive

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I need to use $http.get to grab a json file in my controller:

```
module.controller 'SampleMapController', ($http, $scope) ->
    $http.get('../../highcharts/mapdata/world.geo.json').
        success (data) ->
            $scope.mapData = data # works and logs out correctly
```

And pass that into a directive, which uses that json for mapping purposes:

```
module.directive 'MapDirective', () ->
    require: '?SampleMapController'
    templateUrl: '../template.html'
    link: ($scope) ->
        console.log $scope.mapData # undefined
        $scope.$watch 'an.object.that.contains.more.data',
            (newValue) ->
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container div'
                    }
                    # ... use $scope.mapData somewhere in here to render the global map
                })
            true
```

But I'm not having any luck accessing that $scope, and not sure if I should be putting it on the $rootScope, or event require the controller.

I'm generating a high charts map inside of the `link:`

A detailed explanation of what I'm looking for is in an abstracted [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/votin/2/edit?html,js,console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant inject $scope in directives , instead you can pass scope in your link function in the directive

```
      your should use this : 


      link:function(scope,element,attributes){ // Notice to the function scope

         // Now you have access to the scope , and you can do whaterver you want .

       }
```

**NOTE**
In dependency injection philosophy , In your controller's you can inject $scope as an dependency , and **$** sign is known in angularJS .And the other thing is , dependency injection in controllers does not follow any **order** , I mean 
consider this :

```
  app.controller('YouController',function($scope,$location,$http,...){
       // You see in the injection , I injected $scope first , but it doesn't matter , I mean I can inject $location first , and then $scope , and ...
      // So there is no order here !

     // your stuff here
  });
```

But in directives , order of passing dependencies into the link function **is Important**, on the other hand , names are not important !

```
  app.directive('yourdirective',function(){// you cannot inject $scope here !
      return {

          link : function(scope,element,attributes){// order is important
               // anything that comes first , is scope 
               // Second is always element 
               // Third is always attributes 
               // So you could do this : 
               // function(scooooope,elem,att)
               // See I changed the names , because here names are not important , but the order is important
             }
        }
      });
```

**Edit** : cleared your code : :(

```
   module.directive('MapDirective',function(){
    return{
       require: '?SampleMapController'
       templateUrl: '../template.html'
       link: function(scope){
           console.log scope.mapData 
         // Please test , if still undefiend ;
       }
      }
   })
```

Comment: Is $scope and scope not the same thing?

Comment: Then this would make my example work, which doesn't. It must involve the $http item.

Comment: Brother, I really dont know whats your problem
You said $scope is undefined in your Directive
And I said instead of $scope, you should use scope in all directives
Now what is the other problem ?

Comment: This helped a lot, but more research on getting a JSON response back using $http will need to be done as far as getting that response injected into a directive.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've added a jsBin example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsbin.com/votin/2/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 2):

You can pass scopes to directives. By using `scope` key in your dicrective. Here's a link for more documentation : [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-scope-)

**Directive**

```
// ...
return {
    require: '?SampleMapController',
    restrcit: 'A', // Attribute
    templateUrl: '../template.html',
    scope: {
        mapData: '=' // Bidirectionnal binding with the controller scope.
    },
    link: function( scope, elm, attrs ) {
        scope.$watch( 'mapData', function(newValue) {
            console.log( newValue );
            // ...
        });
};
// ...
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- ... -->
<div data-map-directive data-map-data="mapData"></div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: The link function with scope.$watch explanation helped a bit, but still having issues getting that code to work.